# Count consecutive occurences of values varying in length in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have a bunch of numbers in a numpy array and I test them based on a condition returning a boolean array:

```
np.random.seed(3456)
a = np.random.rand(8)
condition = a>0.5
```

And with this boolean array I want to count all of the lengths of consecutive occurences of True. For example if I had `[True,True,True,False,False,True,True,False,True]` I would want to get back `[3,2,1]`.

I can do that using this code:

```
length,count = [],0
for i in range(len(condition)):

    if condition[i]==True:
        count += 1
    elif condition[i]==False and count>0:
        length.append(count)
        count = 0

    if i==len(condition)-1 and count>0:
        length.append(count)

    print length
```

But is there anything already implemented for this or a python,numpy,scipy, etc. function that counts the length of consecutive occurences in a list or array for a given input?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Numpy grouping using itertools.groupby performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651683/numpy-grouping-using-itertools-groupby-performance)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's a solution using `itertools` (it's probably not the fastest solution):

```
import itertools
condition = [True,True,True,False,False,True,True,False,True]
[ sum( 1 for _ in group ) for key, group in itertools.groupby( condition ) if key ]

Out:
[3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Definitely a very pythonic answer! Actually this is much faster than my code snip that I had above. about 0.2s compared to ~1-2

Comment: It worked... but then it started showing me this error: `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous`. Out of blue, no idea why. It works in idle, byt not in pycharm

Comment: This is slightly faster if you use len(list(group)) instead of sum( 1...), but still significantly slower than @Jaime's answer if you already have a numpy array.

Answer (score 57):

If you already have a numpy array, this is probably going to be faster:

```
>>> condition = np.array([True,True,True,False,False,True,True,False,True])
>>> np.diff(np.where(np.concatenate(([condition[0]],
                                     condition[:-1] != condition[1:],
                                     [True])))[0])[::2]
array([3, 2, 1])
```

It detects where chunks begin, has some logic for the first and last chunk, and simply computes differences between chunk starts and discards lengths corresponding to `False` chunks.

Comment: I'm passing this function to grouby and resample methods on pandas dataframes so I guess it would ultimately be a numpy array. In this case speed isn't much of an issue but noted in case of much larger datasets

Comment: I found this to be a couple orders magnitude faster for 1e6 bools than the itertools approach. Thanks!

Comment: Nice one, thanks! Do you perhaps have a suggestion how I could adapt your code such that I could do this row-wise on a 2D numpy array?

Comment: @pr94 Doing it row wise will likely give different length arrays for each answer. I would guess you would have to do it one row at a time and thus you would just need to loop it some how and add the extra index `[0,:]` instead of `[0]`

Answer (score 3):

You can also count the distance between consecutive `False` values by looking at the index (result of `np.where`) of the inverse of your condition array. The trick is ensuring the boolean array starts with a `False`. Basically, you're counting the distance between the boundaries between your `True` conditions.

```
condition = np.array([True, True, True, False, False, True, True, False, True, False])
if condition[0]:
    condition = np.concatenate([[False], condition])

idx = np.where(~condition)[0]
```

At the final step, you need to 1 from these values so you remove both the left and right edges.

```
>>> np.ediff1d(idx) - 1
array([3, 0, 2, 1])
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
np.unique((~arr).cumsum()[arr], return_counts=True)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If t is the np array and it is sorted in ascending order, then:

```
d=np.diff(t)
d_incr = np.argwhere(d>0).flatten()
d_incr = np.insert(d_incr, 0, 0)
```

The np array d_incr will contain the indices where a change occured, allowing one to perform operations on groups of values between d_incr[i-1] and d_incr[i] for i in range(1,d_incr.size)