# Count consecutive occurrences of values in a .txt file

Tags: python, text

I have a .txt file that has two words repeating in separate lines.

Here is an example. (the actual one is about 80,000 lines long)

```
ANS
ANS
ANS
AUT
AUT
AUT
AUT
ANS
ANS
ANS
ANS
ANS
```

I am trying to develop some Python code to count the consecutive lines and return the number of times they repeat. So for this example I would like to return [3,4,5] to another .txt file

```
word="100011010"
count=1
length=""

for i in range(1, len(word)):

    if word[i-1] == word[i]:
       count += 1

    else:
        length += word[i-1]+" repeats "+str(count)+", "
        count=1

length += ("and "+word[i]+" repeats "+str(count))
print (length)
```

The concept is similar to the above code for a string. Is there a way to do this with a list?

Comment: You can use the exactly same code. Just change `word` with `your_list` :)

Comment: sorry, I worded the last question in the wrong way. Right now the information is in a .txt file, would I have to convert that to a list?

Comment: would there be anyway to read it directly from the .txt file? can a certain line be singled from it (such as word[2]). Is there a way to say line[2]?

Comment: @slyness not sure what your application is, but you may also find this applicable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342047/count-consecutive-occurences-of-values-varying-in-length-in-a-numpy-array

Answer (score 2):

You can read the entire file as this:

```
content = []
with open('/path/to/file.txt', 'r') as file
    content = file.readlines()
    #Maybe you want to strip the lines
    #content = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]
```

Here you have a list with all the lines of the file

```
def count_consecutive_lines(lines):
    counter = 1
    output = ''
    for index in range(1, len(lines)):
        if lines[index] != lines[index-1]:
            output += '{} repeats {} times.\n'.format(lines[index], counter)
            counter = 1
        counter += 1
   return output
```

And call this like

```
print(count_consecutive_lines(content))
```

Comment: thank you I will try this out. Could I do a file.write('\n'.join) to write the counts to another .txt file (\n for a new line for each)?

Comment: @slynes Yes, you can

Answer (score 1):

An answer that doesn't load the whole file into memory:

```
last = None
count = 0
result = []

with open('sample.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == last:
            count = count + 1
        else:
            if count > 0:
                result.append(count)
            count = 1
            last = line

    result.append(count)
    print result
```

Result:

```
[3, 4, 5]
```

**UPDATE**

The list contains integers, you can only `join` strings, so you will have to convert it.

```
outFile.write('\n'.join(str(n) for n in result))
```

Comment: Thanks this worked great. instead of print at the end I am trying to write the result to a .txt file using outFile.write('\n'.join(result)) (outFile already defined), but it is not working for some reason

Comment: @slynes Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert the file data into a list and follow the approach given below:

```
with open("./sample.txt", 'r') as fl:
    fl_list = list(fl)
    unique_data = set(fl_list)
    for unique in unique_data:
        print "%s - count: %s" %(unique, fl_list.count(unique))

#output:
ANS - count: 8
AUT - count: 4
```

Comment: he does not want the total count of a word, rather, the consecutive count of a word, take a look at his example where ans appears in the desired final result, twice.

Comment: Not what the OP wanted .. counting consecutive similar items...not counting all similar items

Comment: that would be good. but would I be able to get the count separately? for example ANS- count: 3, AUT - count: 4, ANS - count: 5. I need to record how many times AUT appears separately.

Answer (score 0):

Open your file and read it to count:

```
l=[]
last=''
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

    for line in data:
        words = line.split()
        if words[0]==last:
            l[-1]=l[-1]+1
            last=words[0]
        else:
            l.append(1)
        if last=='':
            last=words[0]
```

Comment: if condition not syntactically correct, assignment vs comp.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your expected output :)

```
with open("./sample.txt", 'r') as fl:
    word = list(fl)
    count=1
    length=[]
    for i in range(1, len(word)):
        if word[i-1] == word[i]:
           count += 1
        else:
            length.append(count)
            count=1
    length.append(count)
    print (length)

#output as you excpect:
[3, 4, 5]
```