# Count number of consecutive elements in a list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array like so:

```
array([100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,
    100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 100, 100,
    100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,
    100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 100, 100,
    100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 300, 100, 100, 100])
```

I need to count the consecutive number of '100' elements. The '100' elements are separated by values greater than 100.

Output should look like:

```
[5,8,8,7,8,8,7,3]
```

Comment: Using a for loop to append a count to a list

for i in c:
        if(i == 100):
            count += 1
            list.append(count)

Comment: You could use `np.where()` to find the idx with the values, and then split the result array into sub-arrays with consecutive integers (c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361945/detecting-consecutive-integers-in-a-list#comment71456493_2361991) and finally, take the length of each sub-arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple python script:

```
arr = [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,
    100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 100, 100,
    100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,
    100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 100, 100,
    100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 300, 100, 100, 100]

check = arr[0]
result = []
count = 0
for el in arr:
    if el == check:
        count+=1
    else:
        check = el
        if count>1:
            result.append(count)
        count = 1
result.append(count)

print(result)
[5, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert the numpy array into a list like this :

```
a = [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 300, 100, 100, 100]
```

Try :

```
from itertools import groupby
b = [sum(1 for i in g) for k,g in groupby(a) if k==100]
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
b = [5, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way adapting @Jaime's solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342047/count-consecutive-occurences-of-values-varying-in-length-in-a-numpy-array) post:

```
a = np.array([100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,
100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 100, 100,
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,
100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 100, 100,
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 300, 100, 100, 100])

c = a == 100
np.diff(np.where(np.concatenate(([c[0]], c[:-1] != c[1:], [True])))[0])[::2]
# array([5, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7, 3])
```