# Finding palindromic sequences of specified length among consecutive array elements - is a non-loopy solution possible?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider a sample 1D integer numpy array `a`.  Actual instances of `a` could have up to a million elements:

```
a = np.array([2, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4, 2, 4, 7, 8, 7, 1])
```

I need to have a function `pal(n)`  where argument n >= 2.  The function is to identify `n` consecutive elements of `a` that form a palindromic sequence.  It is sufficient to just identify the index of the first element.

examples:
a) pal(5) = [3]   because the 5 consecutive elements starting with index = 3 form the palindromic sequence  (ie: 2,4,5,4,2)

b) pal(3) = [6,9] because the 3 elements starting at index 6 and at index 9 yield palindromic sequences   (ie: 4,2,4   and   7,8,7)

This is fairly straight forward using loops, but I'm wondering if a non-loopy solution is possible.

Comment: Can you share the *fairly straight forward* solution?

Comment: how about using your vector to create a toeplitz matrix, inverting the vector and subtraction it from each row of the toeplitz matrix and then searching for rows with consecutive zeros using [one of the solutions in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342047/count-consecutive-occurences-of-values-varying-in-length-in-a-numpy-array)?

Comment: What do you mean by non-loopy solution ? A solution that use in-built numpy function ? But if those in-built numpy function use a loop behind the hood, is it still a non-loopy solution ? Also a well-written for loop solution is likely to more performant than any other solution, why do you want to use another solution ? And last point, `pal(3)` should output `[4,6,9]` no ?

Comment: I don't quite understand your apparent aversion to using overt loops. As @obchardon has suggested, the "behind the scenes" solutions will be using loops anyway. I have code that will search for all 5-character numeric palindromes in a list containing one million single digit values in ~250ms.

Comment: @DarkKnight - Can you provide a solution with loops, because I think you might be right? I would like to compare the performance impact with  my solution.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Solution provided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer uses an overt loop and performs extremely well. Average duration is ~250ms (excluding construction of the pseudo-random list)

```
import random
from datetime import datetime

s = [random.randint(1, 9) for _ in range(1_000_000)]

def pal(n):
    r = []
    for i in range(len(s) - n + 1):
        a = s[i:i + n]
        if a == a[::-1]:
            r.append(i)
    return r


_start = datetime.now()
result = pal(5)
_end = datetime.now()
print(f'Duration={_end-_start}')
```

Comment: Very fast.  Does the job well.

Comment: I had to modify this line by adding 1 to the range:   for i in range(len(s) - n + 1):

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html) and check if the flipped view is identical. This solution is fully vectorized (*non-loopy*) but creates one additional array with size `(len(a)-n,n)`.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4, 2, 4, 7, 8, 7, 1])

def pal(arr, n):
    x = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(arr, n)
    return np.where(~(x != np.fliplr(x)).any(1))[0]
```

Your test cases:

```
pal(a,3)
```

Output

```
array([4, 6, 9])
```

```
pal(a,5)
```

Output

```
array([3])
```

---

### Micro-Benchmark

Runtime benchmarks for the loop solution against the vectorized solution on a google colab instance in a jupyter notebook.

Results

```
vectorized with 100000
100 loops, best of 5: 3.74 ms per loop
vectorized with 1000000
10 loops, best of 5: 34.9 ms per loop
vectorized with 10000000
1 loop, best of 5: 343 ms per loop
loop with 100000
10 loops, best of 5: 33.3 ms per loop
loop with 1000000
1 loop, best of 5: 346 ms per loop
loop with 10000000
1 loop, best of 5: 3.42 s per loop
```

Code for the benchmark

```
import random
import numpy as  np

def pal_vec(arr, n):
    x = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(arr, n)
    return np.where(~(x != np.fliplr(x)).any(1))[0]

def pal_loop(n):
    r = []
    for i in range(len(s) - n):
        a = s[i:i + n]
        if a == a[::-1]:
            r.append(i)
    return r

#preparing the data
r = [5,6,7]
looparr = [[random.randint(1, 9) for _ in range(10**k)] for k in r]
nparr = [np.array(e) for e in looparr]


# benchmarking
for arr in nparr:
    print(f'vectorized with {len(arr)}')
    %timeit pal_vec(arr,3)
for s in looparr:
    print(f'loop with {len(s)}')
    %timeit pal_loop(3)
```

Comment: Good solution, but it will be interesting to compare the two algorithm for `n=50` for example, since the memory needed by the linearized solution will also increase linearly.

Comment: Very insightful - thank you for taking the time.

Comment: The sliding-window idea is one I can use in other places as well.   When I was doing this manually, that's essentially the approach I used, without knowing it could be coded so compactly.

Comment: I like this solution but get error: 'numpy.lib.stride_tricks' has no attribute 'sliding_window_view'.    Possibly need to update my Numpy version.

Comment: You need `numpy 1.20.0` or newer. You can do the same with [`as_strided`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) but it's failure prone and hard to understand, even the numpy documentation advises to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Just another example where the for loop will probably be faster than a linearized option when `n` start to be bigger :

```
def pal_loop(arr,n):
    r = []                          
    l = -(-n//2)                    #ceiling division
    for i in range(len(arr) - n):   #loop over the array
        for j in range(l):          #compare element pair by pair
            if arr[i+j] != arr[i+n-j]:
                break               #break if one pair is not similar
        r.append(i)
    return r
```

The benchmarking will show almost no difference if `n` is small or if `n` is big.

Comment: Excellent explanation - I need to be less loop-adverse at times!

Comment: for pal_loop(a, 3), I get [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  instead of the correct [4, 6, 9]