# How to group blocks of identical Booleans?

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

Suppose I have the following list:

```
a = [True, True, True, False, False, False, False, True, True]
```

How could get them best grouped by either returning only `0`,`3`, `7` or a grouping like the following?

```
[True, True, True]
[False, False, False, False]
[True, True]
```

Background: I am trying to find plateaus in my NumPy arrays, and while setting the derivative to zero is a good start, I still need to sort the array into chunks. I think this basically boils down to the problem above.

I looked up NumPy and itertools (trying to get a solution from the question *[NumPy grouping using itertools.groupby performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651683/numpy-grouping-using-itertools-groupby-performance#4652265)*) but I did not succeed. I guess one might use a combination of `itertools.takewhile` and filtfalse (see the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee)), but I am out of my depth there. Or maybe I am just thinking way too complicated.

Comment: `itertools.groupby` is certainly the most obvious native python way to do this, what exactly is wrong with it for you? speed, memory, something else?

Comment: Skills, I just have not managed to get a solution to work with itertools.groupby

Comment: `[list(g) for _,g in  itertools.groupby(a)]` creates the lists... but getting the indices isn't so convient I guess, maybe `[next(g)[0] for _,g in  itertools.groupby(enumerate(a), key=lambda x: x[1])]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could get the indices with a sliced array comparison, and it should be good with performance with large size lists/arrays -

```
a_ext = np.r_[~a[0],a]
out = np.flatnonzero(a_ext[:-1]!=a_ext[1:])
```

As a one-liner, we could use `np.diff` + `np.flatnonzero` -

```
np.flatnonzero(np.diff(np.r_[~a[0],a]))
# compact alternative : np.where(np.diff(np.r_[~a[0],a]))[0]
```

Comment: @Idlehands from the question "I'm trying to find plateaus in numpy arrays".  So no, I don't think so.

Comment: @Idlehands Well it's useful when looking for performance on large sized data, I have seen. So, would depend on the requirements I think.

Comment: @Eulenfuchswiesel Thanks for the edit suggestions. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way maybe would be this:

```
a = [True, True, True, False, False, False, False, True, True]

res = [0] + [i+1 for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(a, a[1:])) if x!=y]
print(res)  # -> [0, 3, 7]
```

---

As far as the `groupby` solution goes, you could do:

```
from itertools import groupby

groups = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(a)]
print(groups)  # -> [[True, True, True], [False, False, False, False], [True, True]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this completely with `itertools.groupby`:

**Given**

```
import itertools as it

a = [True, True, True, False, False, False, False, True, True]
```

**Code**

```
[list(g)[0][0] for _, g in it.groupby(enumerate(a), key=lambda x: x[-1])]
# [0, 3, 7]
```

---

**Details**

This is the output of `groupby` from your iterable:

```
[(k, list(g)) for k, g in it.groupby(a)]
# [(True, [True, True, True]),
#  (False, [False, False, False, False]),
#  (True, [True, True])]
```

We can enumerate each item per group (`g`) as tuples and group by the last index in each tuple:

```
[list(g) for k, g in it.groupby(enumerate(a), key=lambda x: x[-1])]
# [[(0, True), (1, True), (2, True)],
#  [(3, False), (4, False), (5, False), (6, False)],
#  [(7, True), (8, True)]]
```

Now we want the first item (`[0]`) and the first position (`[0]`) to get the index of each group.

[Chris_Rands' suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265826/how-to-group-blocks-of-identical-booleans-in-python#comment93415838_53265826) of `[next(g)[0] ...]` is even cleaner.

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45873519/4531270) on how to use `groupby`.