# Split numpy array into segments where condition is met

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array like so:

```
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, -5, -6, 3, 5, 1, -2, 5, -1, -1, 10])
```

I want to get rid of all negative values, and split the array at each index where there was a negative value. The result should look like this:

```
split_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 5, 1], [5], [10]]
```

I know how to do this using list comprehension, but since the array can get quite large and I have to do the calculation many times, I want to find a solution using numpy. I found this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-split-list-into-lists-by-particular-value/, which I can use to split the array where there are negative values, but I can't simultaneously remove them.

Comment: For the linked solution, couldn't you change the condition to `if len(sublist) > 0 and sublist[0] > 0`?

Comment: That removes the subarrays that start with a negative value, but this could remove subarrays that include positive numbers, and also does not remove subarrays that end with negative values. I don't think it quite solves the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that instead of numpy, you could make use of `itertools.groupby` this way (though, judging on this: [NumPy grouping using itertools.groupby performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651683/numpy-grouping-using-itertools-groupby-performance), pure numpy will likely be more efficient):

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby

arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, -5, -6, 3, 5, 1, -2, 5, -1, -1, 10])
split_list = [list(group) for key, group in groupby(arr, key=lambda x:x>=0) if key]

# [[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 5, 1], [5], [10]]
```

Comment: Looks nice, I like it. Any thoughts about the performance of `groupby` on big data?

Comment: I'm not really sure; you might want to read the answers there for insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651683/numpy-grouping-using-itertools-groupby-performance

Answer (score 2):

Get indexes where a sign is changing, use them as bins to split, choose each second array of the result:

```
start = 0 if arr[0] >= 0 else 1
np.split(arr, np.arange(1, len(arr))[np.diff(arr < 0)])[start::2]
```

Note, that `numpy.diff` on boolean data is applying XOR on neighboring elements, as in the example below:

```
data = np.array([1,1,0,0,0,1,1], dtype=bool)
assert all(np.diff(data) == (data[1:] ^ data[:-1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

For a pure numpy approach:

```
m = arr<0
np.split(arr[~m], np.unique((np.arange(m.shape[0])-np.cumsum(m))[m])+1)
```

Or with a loop:

```
m = arr<0
m2 = m & ~np.r_[False, m[:-1]]

out = [a[a>0] for a in np.split(arr, np.nonzero(m2)[0])]
```

Output:

```
[array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([3, 5, 1]), array([5]), array([10])]
```

Intermediates (first approach):

```
np.unique((np.arange(m.shape[0])-np.cumsum(m))[m])+1
# array([4, 7, 8])

arr[~m]
# array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  3,  5,  1,  5, 10])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that leans on the linked example. There is a possible concern re: best practices using `filter` here to remove the empty lists caused by the comprehension...ultimately there are better answers here already, but I wanted to add this for the sake of completeness

```
import numpy as np

# input array
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, -5, -6, 3, 2, 1, -2, 5, -1, -1, 10])
# get indices of negative values
idx = np.where(arr < 0)[0]
# split the input array at that index
subarrays = np.split(arr, idx)
# build the final list, removing all negative values
# ('filter' is used to remove the empty lists caused by 'sub[sub > 0]')
result = list(filter(None, [sub[sub > 0].tolist() for sub in subarrays]))

print(result)
# => [[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 2, 1], [5], [10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
[x[mask] for x in np.split(arr, np.where(arr < 0)[0]) if (mask := x >= 0).any()]
```

Output:

```
[array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([3, 5, 1]), array([5]), array([10])]
```

Comment: Note to future readers: this requires Python 3.8+ since it makes use of the walrus operator, `:=`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, -5, -6, 3, 5, 1, -2, 5, -1, -1, 10])

# Find the indices where the array is negative
neg_indices = np.where(arr < 0)[0]

# Split the array at the indices where it is negative
split_arr = np.split(arr, neg_indices)

# Remove the negative values from each subarray
split_list = [subarr[subarr >= 0] for subarr in split_arr]

# Convert the subarrays to lists and remove any empty lists
split_list = [subarr.tolist() for subarr in split_list if len(subarr) > 0]

print(split_list)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).